# For loop for plotting multiple plots in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

```
for symbol in symbols:
    data = con.get_candles(symbol, period='D1', start = start, end = end)
    data1 = con.get_candles('USOil', period='D1', start = start1, end = end)
    ax = data['bidclose'].plot()
    data1['bidclose'].plot(ax=ax)
```

I have used the code above in the hope that it will plot `symbol` and `usoil` in 1 chart and then produce another chart with the next in line `symbol` and `usoil` until all the symbol list has been exhaused. However evertything is getting plotted in the same chart.

[image]

How can i use the for-loop where 1 symbol in the list of symbols and usoil get plotted? Thus there will be n numbers of plots where n is the number of symbol in symbols.

Comment: I think you could create a new figure everytime through the loop.

Comment: @user1558604 I thought so too but everything is getting plotted in the same chart! I am actually trying to recreate an error`ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis` I hoped it would show up but for some reason it did not!

Comment: This is why I like the object-oriented way, it takes a bit longer to write but you have better control (/ comprehension) over what `ax` and `figure` are shown. It allows to manually open/save/close figures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put `plt.show()` in your routine:

```
for symbol in symbols:
    data = con.get_candles(symbol, period='D1', start = start, end = end)
    data1 = con.get_candles('USOil', period='D1', start = start1, end = end)
    ax = data['bidclose'].plot()
    data1['bidclose'].plot(ax=ax)
    plt.show()
```